# T-SQL: removing Time and Preceding characters from nvarchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a comments column in a SQL Server database table of type `nvarchar` and typically contains text along the lines of:

```
By: SoAndSo 01/01/2020 01:15:10 AM Blah Blah...
```

I am trying to find a way in the select statement to remove the character pattern of '#:#:# AM/PM' and everything preceding it leaving me with "Blah Blah..."

In doing so I don't want to remove legitimate uses of the work 'AM' because sometimes the comments were typed in caps. I tried using charindex but it doesn't seem to allow you to specify patterns as specific as I am searching for. I end up losing legitimate uses of the work 'am'.

Comment: `PATINDEX` is for patterns, `CHARINDEX` is for characters.

Comment: Though is seems like the real problem is you're storing the user and date & time of the comment in the comment body and not in separate columns. Fixing the design is the real solution here.

Comment: User, Date/Time is being stored in other fields so it's redundant in the comments.  That's why I am trying to remove it.  I am using your example to see if I can work through it now.

Comment: Does that mean that you can reliably use the user and date/time from the other columns to assist in removing the problem text?

Comment: @HABO raises a good point, you could then use `CHARINDEX` with the time column to remove the start.

Comment: No, it's inconsistent.  Basically, what they are saying in the comments is important.  Not what date/time or who say it.

Comment: So that value of the time in the comment doesn't match the value of the time column? Then that means that the value of the time in the comment means something else and so (again) should be separated into a separate column. Does the same apply for the user name?

Comment: What's important is the users name and time recorded in the comments is not important to what is happening or what they are describing. So it needs to be removed for the purposes of this query.  patindex('%[0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] [AP]M%'  sees to properly identify time in the field so now I just need to remove it and everything to the left of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `patindex()` to find the pattern and then remove it using `stuff()`:

```
select stuff(col, pos, pos + 22, '')
from (values ('By: SoAndSo 01/01/2020 01:15:10 AM Blah Blah')) t(col) cross apply
     (values (patindex('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] [AP]M%', col))) v(pos);
```

Edit:  Based on your comment:

```
select stuff(col, 1, pos + 22, '')
from (values ('By: SoAndSo 01/01/2020 01:15:10 AM Blah Blah')) t(col) cross apply
     (values (patindex('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] [AP]M%', col))) v(pos);
```

Comment: The solution seems to leave what's to the left of the date/time.  I need to remove that also.  I just want to leave the Blah Blah.  Edit: Sorry I deleted the previous comments because I hit enter too quickly.

Comment: @CharlesBatschelet . . . That is a rather trivial modification to the code.  I added what it looks like.